# Create application bar icon (Expression Design, Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, expression-design

I've been searching Google for hours, and it just keeps coming up with useless results of other peoples `.design` files when I want to learn how to create an application bar icon from scratch, not using their `.design` files. So, how do I do it?

Comment: you can export the .design file to png which can then be used as your application icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guidelines are listed in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431806%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). As an addition: Use PNG, transparent background and white foreground for the final image to let the system invert your icon for the light system theme.

I would recommand to use the basecircle file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons\dark as a little help to set the optimum position of your icon. The circle itself is drawn by the system.